# SQL: Changing SELECT Query to Show Different Values on Column A based off Boolean in Column B

Tags: sql, sum, db2, case

I have a SQL Query that produces this output:
[image: Current Output]

**How would I adjust my query so that the "SCORE" column's value is increased by 3 if the "CROSSDOMAIN" column value is `true?`** I am thinking that I would wrap my existing query with another query that handles this case, but I'm not sure what that query would be.

My existing query is as follows (not the prettiest, but it works):

```
                SELECT HORSUM.TEAMNAME, HORSUM.EMAIL1, SUM(HORSUM.TOTALSUM) Score, COUNT(*) Count, TEAM.THEME, TEAM.FINALIST, TEAM.WINNER, TEAM.CROSSDOMAIN
                FROM 
                    (SELECT "JUDGEEMAIL", "TEAMNAME", "EMAIL1", "DEVOPSPRACTICES" + "BUSINESSIMPACT" + 
                    "NEWSKILLS" + "EXECUTION"
                    + "INNOVATION" + "CLARITY" as totalSum
                    FROM "DOMAINSCORES") AS HORSUM
                INNER JOIN (SELECT "THEME", "TEAMNAME" as nameID, "FINALIST", "WINNER", "CROSSDOMAIN" FROM "TEAMS" WHERE "FINALIST" = True) AS TEAM ON HORSUM.TEAMNAME = TEAM.nameID
                GROUP BY "TEAMNAME", EMAIL1, THEME, FINALIST, WINNER, CROSSDOMAIN
                ORDER BY Score DESC;
```

EDIT: I've tried this query, as suggested by Michael, but I get a syntax error. I also want to add that I am using IBM's DB2, if that makes a difference.

```
SELECT HORSUM.TEAMNAME
     , HORSUM.EMAIL1
     , case
         when TEAM.CROSSDOMAIN = 'true' 
         then SUM(HORSUM.TOTALSUM) + 3
         else SUM(HORSUM.TOTALSUM) 
       end as Score
     , COUNT(*) Count
     , TEAM.THEME
     , TEAM.FINALIST
     , TEAM.WINNER
     , TEAM.CROSSDOMAIN
FROM
(SELECT HORSUM.TEAMNAME, HORSUM.EMAIL1, SUM(HORSUM.TOTALSUM) Score, COUNT(*) Count, TEAM.THEME, TEAM.FINALIST, TEAM.WINNER, TEAM.CROSSDOMAIN
                FROM 
                    (SELECT "JUDGEEMAIL", "TEAMNAME", "EMAIL1", "DEVOPSPRACTICES" + "BUSINESSIMPACT" + 
                    "NEWSKILLS" + "EXECUTION"
                    + "INNOVATION" + "CLARITY" as totalSum
                    FROM "DOMAINSCORES") AS HORSUM
                INNER JOIN (SELECT "THEME", "TEAMNAME" as nameID, "FINALIST", "WINNER", "CROSSDOMAIN" FROM "TEAMS" WHERE "FINALIST" = True) AS TEAM ON HORSUM.TEAMNAME = TEAM.nameID
                GROUP BY "TEAMNAME", EMAIL1, THEME, FINALIST, WINNER, CROSSDOMAIN)
ORDER BY Score DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as outer SELECT

```
SELECT HORSUM.TEAMNAME
     , HORSUM.EMAIL1
     , case
         when TEAM.CROSSDOMAIN = 'true' 
         then SUM(HORSUM.TOTALSUM) + 3
         else SUM(HORSUM.TOTALSUM) 
       end as Score
     , COUNT(*) Count
     , TEAM.THEME
     , TEAM.FINALIST
     , TEAM.WINNER
     , TEAM.CROSSDOMAIN
     ...
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the quick response. I'm trying the query as follows, but I get an error "HORSUM.TEAMNAME" is not valid in the context where it is used. Any ideas?

Comment: See my edit to the original question above for what i'm trying.

Comment: You built an additional outer select that is why you run into this problem - replace the outer most select of the original query (your first SELECT)

Comment: Thanks so much Michael, should've realized that's what you meant. Sorry about that!